# Error when trying to install plotly

Tags: python

```
pip install plotly
```

Gave me a permissions error

```
sudo pip install plotly
```

Worked and installed plotly, tried to 'import plotly' , ImportError: No module named 'plotly'

---

now when i do this again:

```
pip install plotly
```

"Requirement already satisfied" but still doesnt import.

```
sudo pip install plotly --upgrade
```

OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-PbshIM-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info'

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Are you running Mac OS X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're on a Mac, running `pip` will install a package into the Mac's own copy of Python 2.7. You're then running Python, which is likely Python 3 and hence *not* the Mac's own copy.

To `pip install` something into your installation of Python 3, use `pip3` instead:

```
sudo pip3 install plotly
```

Comment: Why is it "likely" to be Python 3? There are lots of scenarios where this is not the case, to the point where I would guess that's more "likely".